# get return value from stored procedure without output parameter

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a vb.net application that inserts records into a db table using a stored procedure that is supposed to return a value. This stored procedure was setup by someone else and initially was linked to a webservice through which my application made the insert and got the return value in the returned xml. I now have access to the db table and not sure how to receive the return value in my vb.net method.

SQl stored procedure snippet;

```
     @urlname varchar(500),
@siteid varchar(16),
@origin varchar(50),
@queryid varchar(25)
  AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @cnt int
declare @serverip varchar(16)
declare @mincnt int
declare @siteservercnt int
select @cnt=COUNT(*) from sites
      where urlname=@urlname
if @cnt = 0
    begin
    insert into sites (urlname,siteid,exported,origin,queryid)
    values(@urlname,@siteid,1,@origin,@queryid)
    select @siteservercnt = COUNT(*) from siteserverip where siteid=@siteid
    if @siteservercnt=0
       begin
            select top 1 @mincnt=COUNT(*),@serverip=serverip from siteserverip
        group by serverip
        order by COUNT(*)
        select top 1 @mincnt=sitecount,
                         @serverip=serverip from serveripcounts
        order by sitecount
        insert into siteserverip values(@siteid,@serverip)
        update serveripcounts set sitecount=sitecount+1
        where serverip=@serverip
        end
    end
SELECT siteid from sites
where urlname=@urlname
return
```

and my vb.net code to do the insert

```
        CommandObj.CommandText = "Getsite"
        CommandObj.CommandTimeout = 90

        Dim newUrl As String = String.Empty

        CommandObj.Parameters.Clear()

        Dim m_param As SqlParameter

        m_param = CommandObj.Parameters.Add("@urlname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500)
        m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        m_param.Value = name


        m_param = CommandObj.Parameters.Add("@siteid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16)
        m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        m_param.Value = siteid

        m_param = CommandObj.Parameters.Add("@origin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        m_param.Value = method

        m_param = CommandObj.Parameters.Add("@queryId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25)
        m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        m_param.Value = forumID


        Dim recordsAffected As Integer = CommandObj.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Comment: `SELECT @MySiteID = SiteID FROM Sites WHERE urlname = @UrlName
RETURN @MySiteID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) to get that value. [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) returns number of rows affected while you want to get the value generated by last select. You could use [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) as well but that is useful when your SP might be returning more columns and/or more rows.

```
'Populate first column and first row value in siteID
Dim siteID As Integer = CommandObj.ExecuteScalar
```